# CP-symmetery conservation

Tags: cp-violation, pions

How can one show that for a given decay, say $\pi^+ \rightarrow \nu_\mu + \mu^+$, CP-symmetry is conserved or violated? Is there a visual way of doing such?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it can be done just with this decay, as stated. I think you need the know the angular momentum and the spin of your particles to calculate the helicity

$$
h=\frac{\vec{s}\cdot\vec{l}}{|{\vec{s}\cdot\vec{l}|}}.
$$

if you find e.g. an anti-neutrino with the wrong helicity you'd know that CP is violated.

Comment: Well, the pion is considered to be in it's rest frame and has spin 0. This way the anti-muon and neutrino should have opposite and equal spin and momenta. This results in both the anti-muon and the neutrino being right-handed and thus a violation of parity (since not as many left- as right-handed particles are produced). Now how can one show that applying the Charge-Conjugation operator after the Parity operator (or vice versa) the CP-symmetry is conserved?